# Get client IP in Wi-fi Direct connection in Android

Tags: android, sockets, wifi-direct

I'm developing a application based on WiFi Direct that connect two devices.

I followed the demo in the Android documentation and already read some answers here at StackOverflow to similar problems.

My workflow is as follows, in order to get the client IP on the host I:

- Create a `ServerSocket` in the GroupOwner that receives a string (client ip) from the client on a pre-determined port;
- In the client I send his IP through a socket to the owner to that port;
- When the owner receives the IP it shows a button to open the gallery (like in the client - like in the demo application)

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {
    this.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // After the group negotiation, we assign the group owner as the file
    // server. The file server is single threaded, single connection server
    // socket.
    if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
        isGroupOwner = true;
        // ServerSocket that receives the message from the client 
        new MessageReceiveSocket(mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client), this).execute();
        new FileReceiveSocket(getActivity()).execute();

    } else if (info.groupFormed) {
        mPeerIP = info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();
        // The other device acts as the client. In this case, we enable the
        // get file button.
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        new FileReceiveSocket(getActivity()).execute();
        // Socket that sends the message to the owner
        SocketUtils.sendMessageToServer(info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress(), SocketUtils.SERVER_MESSAGE_PORT);
    }
    // hide the connect button
    mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

My problem is when I disconnect both devices, and connect again both devices, I receive this error on the client:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 8989) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

The problem must be that the `ServerSocket` is not terminated, but I don't understand why or how should I correct it.

Comment: `that receives a string (client ip) on a pre-determined port;` ? Received from who? `In the client I send his IP through a socket to the owner to that port;` why would you do that? A server by itself knows the ip of all clients. `When the owner receives the IP it shows a button to open the gallery (like in the client)` ? The gallery? Which gallery? Like on the client? Can you explain better what all should happen?

Comment: I edited to better explain my problem.

Comment: You added some code. But you did not explain better. In fact you did not answer one of my remarks/questions. Why not?

Comment: - `Received from who?` From the client
- `why would you do that? A server by itself knows the ip of all clients.` How can a `GroupOwner` in a WifiP2p connection know the ip of the other devices? I can only know the MAC addresses of them.
- `The gallery? Which gallery? Like on the client? Can you explain better what all should happen?` Just replicating de `WiFiDirectDemo` in the Android SDK Samples.

Comment: I was not referring to a group owner but to your serversocket. And wondered why a client of this serversocket would send its ip address to that serversocket as the serversocket would know that already at the moment the client connected. A serversocket knows the ip addresses of all its clients.

Comment: But in my case I want to be able to send a file to the `FileReceiveSocket` of the client from the owner. And I want to be able to send that `File` from the owner even if the client did not send nothing previously.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to find a solution for it?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution ?